# java code for showing xlsx file content in grid

Tags: java

I need to upload `xlsx` file in to local folder and I need to show that `xlsx` file in grid format so  I have uploaded file in to local folder but I need code for showing `xlsx` file in grid format.

My code is:

```
ist<FileItem> multiparts = upload.parseRequest(request);

for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
    if (!item.isFormField()) {
        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
        System.out.println("name::::"+name);
        item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `apache poi` for reading either `xls` or `xlsx`

Answer (score 1):

Below there is a class to write in .xlsx file. Note to run this file you will need to download [Apache poi lib](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) and add all .jar files in your project 
In the code I am writing an.xlsx file with A to Z characters and its ASCII values. I am also written the comments in code so that it is easy to understand the code and if you still have a doubt please comment.

```
    package com;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    public class WriteSheet 
    {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
         {
             //Creating a blank workbook
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
             //Creating a blank sheet
             XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet( 
             "ASCII Values from A to Z");      
             int j=0;
             int ascii=65;
             for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
             {
                //Creating row object
                XSSFRow row= spreadsheet.createRow(i); 
                //Creating a cell
                Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
                j++;
                //Adding values to cell
                cell.setCellValue(""+ascii);
               //Creating a new cell in same row
               cell = row.createCell(j);
               //Adding values to new cell
               cell.setCellValue(""+(char)ascii);
               ascii++;
               j=0;          
           }
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( 
           new File("C:\\Users\\TANAY\\Desktop\\Writesheet.xlsx"));
           workbook.write(out);
           out.close();
           System.out.println( 
           "Writesheet.xlsx written successfully" );
           workbook.close();
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Apache POI`](https://poi.apache.org/) you can read and write `MS Excel` files. It’s able to handle both `XLS` and `XLSX` formats of spreadsheets. You can work with Formulas, Fonts, Images, Styles, etc. In addition, you can read and write `MS Word` and `MS PowerPoint` files.

[Here is the example of Apache POI.](http://www.journaldev.com/2562/java-readwrite-excel-file-using-apache-poi-api)

Answer (score 0):

In Below  class I am reading from .xlsx file and displaying the data, I am writing this separately  so there will no confusion in writing .xlsx and reading .xlsx file. Note to run this file you will need to download [Apache poi lib](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) and add all .jar files in your project. I am also written the comments in code so that it is easy to understand the code and if you still have a doubt please comment

```
package com;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class ReadSheet 
{
   static XSSFRow row;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {  
      //File to be read
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\TANAY\\Desktop\\Writesheet.xlsx"));
      //Creating workbook object
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      //getting a spreadsheet
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      //to get last row number in spreadsheet
      int rowcount=spreadsheet.getLastRowNum();
      int j=0;
      for (int i=0; i<=rowcount; i++)
      {
         //getting a row
         row= spreadsheet.getRow(i);
         //getting a cell
         Cell cel= row.getCell(j);
         //printing value of cell
         System.out.print(cel.getStringCellValue());
         j++;
         //getting next cell from same row
         cel=row.getCell(j);
         //displaying cell values
         System.out.print("    "+cel.getStringCellValue());
         j=0;
         System.out.println();
      }
     fis.close();
     workbook.close();
   }
}
```